# Error Converter returns object with null values

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

So I'm using retrofit to execute my API calls, and I have this endpoint which is returning error (which is the desired response), when I try to use my converter to turn the response.errorBody() into my java object Error, it returns the new Error object but its fields are null.

Here's my Error object class:

```
public class Error {
     private final String message;
     private final Object objectError;


    public Error(String message, Object objectError) {
        this.message = message;
        this.objectError = objectError;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Object getObjectError() {
        return objectError;
    }
}
```

Here's my converter method:

```
public static Error parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, Error> converter = ApiClient.retrofit().responseBodyConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);

        Error error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new Error("Connection Error", null);
        }

        return error;
}
```

And my JSON response looks alright:

```
{"status":"error",
   "error":{"message":"# is an invalid character",
                 "objectError":"# is an invalid character"}}
```

Can you please help me find out what's happening?

Massive thanks!

Comment: As a note, **very strongly avoid** naming your class `Error`, as it conflicts with `java.lang.Error`. Prefix it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @chrylis, but I only named it like that in the post. It actually has a different name on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by creating another class that has the status field and the error field, and used that one in the converter, the error field in that class is the one above.